# Finding value of (y) of logarithmic equation given (x)

Tags: logarithms, matlab, nonlinear-system, maxima-software, octave

I have an logarithmic equation
$$\left[ r=a\,e^{b\,\theta} \right] $$

And I plot it to visualise it (see plot below).
I can tell by the plot when **(t=0), x1=0, y=1** *(point AA)*
but how can I find out numerically what  **(y2)** *point BB* will be when **x2=.5** (*the red dot on the plot (point BB)*) by using an equation.

[image]

Eq Solve for a
$$\left[ a={{r}\over{e^{b\,\theta}}} \right] $$

Eq to Solve for b
$$\left[ b={{\log \left({{r}\over{a}}\right)}\over{\log e\,\theta
 }} \right] $$

Eq to Solve for theta
$$\left[ \theta={{\log \left({{r}\over{a}}\right)}\over{b\,\log e
 }} \right] $$

I tried solving the equations using maxima but it came back with a large list of logs instead of a one numerical value.

```
kill(all);
r:.5; a:1; b:-5.7; theta:theta; solve(a*e^(b*theta)=r,theta);
tex(''%);
```

I'm still at a loss as to how to find (y2) at point BB when (x2=.5) (y2=?)

Ps:  I'll be using octave 3.8.1 to calculate these values which is like matlab but I'm just trying to get the
equations worked out correctly.

Comment: How do $y_2$ and $x_2$ relate to the variables in your first equation? I suggest rewriting this in terms of one set of variables (or at least explaining what they're for).

Comment: @RickT You need another (known) data point or something similar to evaluate the coordinates of BB.

Comment: @horchler y2 and x2 are just the x and y values for point BB  x2 and t are the same thing.  I'll fix the plot and update

Comment: It looks like $x$ is just $\theta$ and $r$ is $y$. Your question would be a lot clearer if you picked one set or the other.

Comment: @horchler yes that sounds correct sorry for the confusion

Comment: @RickT No other additional information ? What is the context of the graph ?

Comment: @calculus I've update the plot image it should have said (x2=t=.5) (y2=?)

Comment: I'm just unclear what your actual question is. $\theta$ is just $y$ and you've solved for $\theta$ (some obvious simplification could still be applied). Is it about programming with Maxima (possibly off-topic for this site)? Is it about how to evaluate a symbolic expression at numerical values (also more about programming than math)? Or is it about how to solve an equation like your first one for $\theta$ numerically without symbolic math?

Comment: @RickT This was obvious to me before your edit, but it is helpful anyway. Try to get more information. To repeat my question: What is the context of the graph ?

Comment: @calculus the context is t starts at 0 and I want t to stop when x2=t=.5  then find out what y2 is.

Comment: @horchler it's more about how to solve an equation like my first one for θ numerically without symbolic math, I plan on converting it to matlab code.

Comment: @RickT This graph is not based on a real (or constructed) problem, like something is decreasing exponentially ?

Comment: @calculus the data taken from the problem above will be used to modulate an audio signal...Experimenting with different types of fade in's and fade out's

Comment: @RickT Is the value for b known ? I´m a little confused about that. The answer of horchler  made this assumption.

Comment: @calculus yes in the image a and b are the sliders a=1 and b=-5.7

Comment: @RickT Now I understand your problem. You just had to insert the values in your equation $ \theta=\frac{\frac{log(0.5)}{1}}{-5.7\cdot log (e)}=\frac{log(0.5)}{-5.7\cdot 1}\approx 0.121605$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you're trying to solve for $\theta$ (i.e., $x_2$) in $ r = a e^{b \theta}$ and are unable to find an analytical solution. You can use numerical [root-finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm). In Matlab and Octave `fzero` ([documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/fzero.html)) solves for roots/zeros of simple [univariate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univariate) functions. The first step is to re-write your equation as $ 0 = a e^{b \theta}-r$. Then, with `th0` as an initial guess, you can solve for a root via:

```
a = 1;
b = -5.7;
r = 0.5;
th0 = 1;
f = @(th)a*exp(b*th)-r;
[th_sol,fval,exitflag] = fzero(f,th0)
```

This returns `0.121604768519289` for `th_sol`. In this case, this is equivalent to the analytical solution $\theta = \text{log}(r/a)/b$.

Of course if you're solving for $y_2$ (i.e., $r$), you don't need to do anything special. Just evaluate:

```
a = 1;
b = -5.7;
th = 0.5;
r = a*exp(b*th)
```